# How to keep $_POST data on browser reload

Tags: php, android

I have a `PHP` page that gets `$_POST` variables from previous `PHP` page. Now the problem is when I reload this web page in chrome in my `android` phone, the `$_POST` variables gets removed instead of resending it. This doesn't happen in browsers in computers or other browsers from my android phone. How can I make it so that `$_POST` variables do resend when chrome browser in my android phone reloads? Do I have to perhaps change some settings in my chrome browser app?

Comment: implement `session` to achieve this.

Comment: this can be done even without sessions

Answer (score 0):

Self Answer: Using GET instead of POST seemed to solve these problems.